# asp.net change/write html to page before pageload event (c sharp)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have some long code on server side that runs on `Page_Load()`. My problem is that users don't see nothing until this code is over

I want to show them some loading picture so that they will know that something is happening. I tried to put some `JavaScript` alert() on page but it didn't helped. I tried to changed html from server-side but of course it only shows the changes after job is done.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // show user a loading image
    // start heavy coding
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at `UpdatePanel` or using AJAX..

Comment: There's more to this than you think.  *Nothing* is rendered to the client until server-side processing is done.  If you want something on the client then you'll need to return a page immediately and on that page have some JavaScript code which makes AJAX requests to the server to conduct the server-side processing and modifies the page in response to those requests.

Comment: i can use ajax
but then ill need to initial that ajax from the aspx page 
and the problem is that the pageload event fire before the aspx page loads am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX or UpdatePanel to separate loading and user-visualizing processes.
In this case you just need pageLoad() - js function, which will call proper, for example, web-service-method and shows loading image. OnSuccess\OnError events if ajax call will help you to handle the result of this call

Comment: i dont have any problem to build an pageLoad() js function

problem is that the heavy coding asp.net PageLoad event

so i cant call any JS function before pageload is ending ...

Comment: you CAN,but you just need to do it dynamically. This should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb412167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx